# Should decoded URI be passed into ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using ***tomcat 7.0.52***

According to the API: [HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()). ServletPath should be a decoded path. However, when I do

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(newUri).forward(request, response);
```

having `newUri` being the lowercased version of the original Uri. The new `getServletPath()` returns identical encoded path as the `getRequestURI()`, which is identical to the `newUri` that I passed in.

Tomcat's API doesn't specify whether `getRequestDispatcher()` should expect an encoded or decoded URI. I am not sure if I should do decoding logic ahead or not. Now I'm facing two solutions, both could have dangerous consequences:

1. **Pass in encoded URI to `getRequestDispatch()`**:
   This mess up the logic that I have in the system because Spring's `@PathVariable` gets String extracted from `ServletPath`. Now it becomes encoded. and I'm afraid of this having other unrevealed issue that is dangerous.
2. **Pass in decoded URI to `getRequestDispatch()`**: In this case, `getRequestURI()` will then receive the decoded version of the URI.

May I ask for some expert's opinion here?

Comment: That's not Tomcat's API you've cited, it is the offiical Servlet Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same question. Tried it out.

**Short answer**: when calling `getRequestDispatcher(path)`, path **must be encoded**.

**Details**: (Spring Boot app on embedded Tomcat 8.5.6)

First I registered a servlet mapped on `/ačiū gal?/*` (path with some symbols not allowed in URL encoding).

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new TestServlet(),"/ačiū gal?/*");
}
```

After that calling `req.getRequestDispatcher("/ačiū gal?/test")` produced:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
 > servletPath = "/ačiū gal"
 > pathInfo = null
 > requestURI = "/greeting-app/a%C4%8Di%C5%AB%20gal"
 > queryString = "/test"
```

And `req.getRequestDispatcher("/a%C4%8Di%C5%AB%20gal%3F/test")` produced:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
 > servletPath = "/ačiū gal?"
 > pathInfo = "/test"
 > requestURI = "/greeting-app/a%C4%8Di%C5%AB%20gal%3F/test"
 > queryString = null
```

As you can see, the second case (encoded path) is what is expected.